# Field duplicating in Mongo when editing page, only one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a page that updates users information, when I edit anything else on the page it edits just fine and displays correctly. however on the city portion it just appends to the field vs updating it. So I get lots of cities vs just one!

front end form:

```
<form action ="/user/<%= user._id %>/?_method=PUT" method="POST">

<section class="side_nav_content">

                <section id="name_and_address_section" class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="user[username]" placeholder="Username" value ="<%= user.username %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="nickname">Nickname</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="nickname" type="text" name="user[profile.nickname]" placeholder="Nickname" value="<%= user.profile.nickname %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="email">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email@wherever.com" value="<%= user.email %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="first">First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="first" type="text" name="user[name][first]" placeholder="First Name" value="<%= user.name.first %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="middle">Middle Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="middle" type="text" name="user[name][middle]" placeholder="Middle Name" value="<%= user.name.middle %>" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="last">Last Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user[name][last]" placeholder="Last Name" value="<%= user.name.last %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="address">Street Address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text" name="user[address]" placeholder="Street Address" value="<%= user.address %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="city">City</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="city" type="text" name="user[city]" placeholder="City" value="<%= user.city %>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="zip">Zip Code</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="zip" type="number" name="user[zipCode]" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<%= user.zipCode %>">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Cancel</a>
                </section>
```

Here is the route:

```
router.put("/user/:id", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
console.log(req.user.username);
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id,
    {$set: req.body.user},
    {save: true, upsert: true, runValidators: true, new: true}, function(err, updatedUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(updatedUser.username);
            res.render("admin", {user: updatedUser});
        }
    })
});
```

Here is the user Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {type:String, required: true, unique: true},
email: {type: String, required: false, unique: false},
password: { type: String, required: true},
resetPasswordToken: String,
resetPasswordExpires: Date,
profile: {picture: String, nickname: String},
permission:{app: Number}, //This will tell the app what level, 0 for Admin, 1 for User
name: {
    first:String,
    middle:String,
    last:String,
    other: {
        startDate: Date,
        endDate: Date,
        first: String,
        middle: String,
        last: String
    }
},
lastName: String,
address: String,
city: String,
state: String,
zipCode: Number,
phone: Number,
birthday: Date,
birthplace: String,
userCover: String,
categories: Array,
defaultPermission: Number,
events: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Event"
}],
moments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Moments"
}],
instants: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Instant"
}],
groups: [
    {family:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"}
    },
     {friends:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
    },
    {colleagues:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
    }],
likedMoments: [{ //This is for what this person likes, so they can refer later
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Moments"
}],
likedEvents: [{  //This is for what this person likes, so they can refer later
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Event"
}],
favoriteEvents: [{ //This is for personal events that are favorited
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "Event"
}],
favoriteMoments: [{  //This is for personal moments that are favorited
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Moments"
}]
})
```

The data will just add to `city` but any other field it just updates, Im not sure what to do as Im not treating city any different. As you can see Im just Updating the entire document at once?

Comment: Does it show any error on the console? Can you share the User schema?

Comment: I have updated the OP with the schema. I do not see any errors

Comment: You are passing the value `req.body.user` to `$set`. I don't see anything as `user` in your form. Are you using a client side javascript function to set the value of `user` in request body? Have you checked if the values are getting set correctly (to match the structure of `userSchema`)?

Comment: look at the `name` attribute in the div's they are `name[username]` etc....
All of those show up in req.body.user

Comment: I just notice an error, I typed `name[username]` it actually reads `user[username]`

Comment: AFAIK naming form elements with JSON key structure will not automatically convert it into a JSON of that structure. But, I may be wrong because you are saying that the server is receiving values in `req.body.user`. Can you copy-paste here the value of `req.body.user` that you receive on the server side?

Comment: `email: 'ilhyf@yahoo.com', address: '220 N Manay Ln',  city: 'r,t,5,a,,Phoenix,Phoenix,Phoenix,Phoenix` Here is a snippet. with the offending `city` field, and 2 fields that are working correctly.

Comment: Also this is the convention I have been using on my entire site, so the structure is working.  Whether its sent back in JSON I am not sure, but I am using `body-parser` in node to retrieve that value, maybe thats the difference?

Comment: Well as you can see, the `user` key is missing from the request body. I would suggest naming the elements in a simpler format `username`, `email`, `first` etc. Then, you can manipulate the values received  on server side to a structure that is expected by the schema. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thats just a snippet as I said its too long to post the whole thing. But why does the entire rest of the form work fine and this one field not? That cant be just because of the user field. which the _id is there. FYI

Comment: In that case, the last thing to check - Do you have any middleware/hooks (`pre('save')`, `pre('validate')`, `post('validate')` etc)? If yes, check if the data is getting modified in those middleware/hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a an input down in another part of the page where `user[city]` was referenced and being saved again. So it was being populated there and when saving it saved both the old value and the new value of the first field!

Maybe this will help someone with a similar issue in the future.